# Invalid default value for current timestamp field in live server

Tags: mysql, timestamp

Below query works fine in my localhost but When i try to execute this query in the live server it gives sql error

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `tbl_claims` (
`id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
`claimed_profile_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
`claimed_by_profile_id` int(11) NOT NULL COMMENT 'this will be only doctor''s profile id',
`name` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
`email` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
`phone_no` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
`status` enum('approved','disapproved','pending') NOT NULL DEFAULT 'pending',
`added_on` datetime NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP, PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
 ) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 AUTO_INCREMENT=4 ;
```

It gives below error:

```
 Invalid default value for 'added_on'
```

I do not know why the above query works fine in loalhost and why it does not work in live server.

The server where the query does not work has PHP Version 5.6.33

Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: We need to know the MySQL version, not the PHP version...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suspect it is because you are trying to use `CURRENT_TIMESTAMP` as the default value for a `datetime` field.

[For MySQL >= 5.6](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/data-type-defaults.html):

> The `DEFAULT` value clause in a data type specification indicates a default value for a column. With one exception, the default value must be a constant; it cannot be a function or an expression. This means, for example, that you cannot set the default for a date column to be the value of a function such as `NOW()` or `CURRENT_DATE`. The exception is that you can specify `CURRENT_TIMESTAMP` as the default for `TIMESTAMP` **and** `DATETIME` columns.

[For MySQL <= 5.5](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/data-type-defaults.html):

> The `DEFAULT` value clause in a data type specification indicates a default value for a column. With one exception, the default value must be a constant; it cannot be a function or an expression. This means, for example, that you cannot set the default for a date column to be the value of a function such as `NOW()` or `CURRENT_DATE`. The exception is that you can specify `CURRENT_TIMESTAMP` as the default for a `TIMESTAMP` column.

As you can see, for versions 5.5 and below, you can only use `CURRENT_TIMESTAMP` as the default value for a `TIMESTAMP` field.